# How to filter missing inner key by using jq

Tags: json, filter, jq

Got a json input like this:

```
[ 
  {
    "dimensions": "helloworld",
    "metrics": "sum(is_error)",
    "values": {
      "timestamp": 1558322460000,
      "value": "0.0"
    }
  },
  {
    "dimensions": "helloworld",
    "metrics": "sum(is_error)",
    "values": {
      "timestamp": 1558322160000,
      "value": "0.0"
    }
  },
  {
    "dimensions": "helloworld",
    "metrics": "sum(is_error)",
    "values": "3423.25"
  }
]
```

The third object doesnot have a timestamp on it. How could I return all the object only have a timestamp on it. Like the following:

```
[ 
  {
    "dimensions": "helloworld",
    "metrics": "sum(is_error)",
    "values": {
      "timestamp": 1558322460000,
      "value": "0.0"
    }
  },
  {
    "dimensions": "helloworld",
    "metrics": "sum(is_error)",
    "values": {
      "timestamp": 1558322160000,
      "value": "0.0"
    }
  }
]
```

Many thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:
`[ .[] | select (.values | has("timestamp")?) ]`

https://jqplay.org/s/n5jsRsPMhW

Or alternative:
`[ .[] | select (.values.timestamp?) ]`

https://jqplay.org/s/HRWV44YgUp

P.S. [This one](https://jqplay.org/s/B1iS41Gk6t) was incorrect because of after .[] you are working with each item separately, not with array. So 'map' function is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot llkiv, this fix my issue. And thanks a lot for telling why my attempt doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
map( select ( .values | has("timestamp")? ))
```

Comment: Thanks peak, but I got and error saying "jq: error (at <stdin>:22): Cannot index string with string "values"
exit status 5". Any idea? See my snippet: https://jqplay.org/s/B1iS41Gk6t

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed that one of the .values is a string. See the update for one alternative.

Answer (score 2):

and here's an alternative solution, using a walk-path unix tool for JSON: **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<timestamp>l:[-2]' -j
[
   {
      "dimensions": "helloworld",
      "metrics": "sum(is_error)",
      "values": {
         "timestamp": 1558322460000,
         "value": "0.0"
      }
   },
   {
      "dimensions": "helloworld",
      "metrics": "sum(is_error)",
      "values": {
         "timestamp": 1558322160000,
         "value": "0.0"
      }
   }
]
bash $
```

- it finds each (all) label `timestamp`, then goes 2 levels up from the found json entry and prints found Json element. `-j` wraps all printed walks back into array.

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` tool